# Zeta zeros standard normal distribution

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

Below is a partially scaled plot of $\vartheta (\gamma_n) - \pi (n - 3/2) ,$ where $\gamma_n$ is the imaginary part of the $n$th zeta zero, and $\vartheta $ is the Riemann-Siegel theta function, for the first $2$m zeros:

[image]

It certainly looks to have standard normal distribution, is this indeed the case?

**Note**

Cross-posted and answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219097/zeta-zeros-standard-normal-distribution-about-vartheta-gamma-n)

Comment: Good question. The theta function solves the heat equation as does the normal distribution, therefore, I would guess the two should be similar. Additionally, the normal density functions are the fixed points of the Fourier transform. So, again, I'd really be interested in seeing an answer to this.

Comment: Firstly, there are theorems about about the "randomness" of zeta zeros. (This is a comment rather than an answer because I don't have references and so on to hand.) You also have quite a lot of data there, and hence the Central Limit Theorem is probably going to kick in.

Comment: @JamieLannister isn't that the Jacobi theta function?

Comment: @martin You're right. I skimmed the explanation really quickly.